# loca table not found

Tags: fonts, luatex

I'm trying to create a PDF from a file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Color Emoji}
\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Running the command:

```
lualatex test.tex
```

produces these log messages:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)
restricted system commands enabled.
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.059 seconds
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))) (./test.aux) [1{/var/
lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux))
410 words of node memory still in use:
  3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 5 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
  avail lists: 2:15,3:4,4:1,5:21,6:1,7:15,9:7
</usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
```

and ends with this error message:

```
! error:  (file /usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf) (ttf): loca table not found
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I've installed the font using

```
pacman -S noto-fonts-emoji
```

and there's indeed a file at

```
/usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
```

How do I get this to compile?

---

I'm not tied to LuaLaTeX; if I can create the PDF with another rendering engine, I'll happily do so.

Comment: See also https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/issues/190.

Comment: Hi @Matthias Braun, I reproduce the example above and yes, we need to wait to Arch Linux update TeX Live 2020 or use lualatex-dev, that not exists at the moment. 

News on TexLive 2020: LuaTeX: Integration with HarfBuzz library, available as new engines luahbtex (used for lualatex) and luajithbtex. New primitives: \eTeXgluestretchorder, \eTeXglueshrinkorder. Please [see](https://listserv.rediris.es/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ES-TEX;e7245dba.2004).