# How to use emoji package for lualatex with TeX Live 2019 (fontproblem)

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive-2019

I want to use the emoji package from texlive luatex. I have TexLive 2019 under Ubuntu 20.04.

I utilized the following commands to install the package, which is not part of the ubuntu texlive distribution:

```
tlmgr init-usertree

tlmgr repository add ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
tlmgr repository list
tlmgr repository remove http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final

tlmgr install emoji  --verify-repo=none
```

My minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{emoji}
\setemojifont{Noto Color Emoji}

\begin{document}

\emoji{grinning}

\end{document}
```

Trying to compile this with lualatex-dev results in no PDF-file but a warning and an error message:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./emoji.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
 L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/andreas/texmf/tex/lualatex/emoji/emoji.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))) (./emoji.aux
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

Package emoji Warning: It seems that you have not declare an emoji font.
(emoji)                You should use "\setemojifont " to set a font.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./emoji.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:17,3:2,4:1,5:21,6:1,7:13,9:7
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></usr/share/fo
nts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf
! error:  (file /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf) (ttf): loca 
table not found
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I also tried `\setemojifont{NotoColorEmoji.ttf}[Path=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/]` and `\setemojifont{Emoji One}` but I get an equivalent result.

The fonts are installed, and in the place indicated by the lualatex message. Lualatex works, and I can set different fonts using `\setmainfont{}`.

I looked at [loca table not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507987/loca-table-not-found) and [How to use Noto Color Emoji with lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497403/how-to-use-noto-color-emoji-with-lualatex) but neither concerns the emoji package and neither contains a working solution for my problem. The first is closed and the second does not contemplate the relevant error message `loca table not found`.

I can use the emoji package with `Twitter Color Emoji` and `Segoe UI Emoji`, but the result is black and white.

So, is there any way to get the emoji package to work with TexLive 2019, Ubuntu 20.04 and `Noto Color Emoji` or `Emoji One`?

Comment: At best get a current texlive 21. You need a luatex with HarfBuzz included, and that is rather new, and there have been some development in the last years

Comment: My luatex from texlive 19 already includes harfbuzz. I also tried to use the option ```Renderer=Halfbuzz``` but nothing changes.

Comment: no, your log shows that you are using `luatex`, that hasn't harfbuzz. You need `luahbtex`. Try to compile with `lualatex-dev`, perhaps that uses already luahbtex on your system.

Comment: Actually, I was compiling with ```lualatex-dev```. But now I discovered that for Ubuntu's (Debian's) texlive ```lualatex-dev``` is a softlink to ```luatex``` as is ```lualatex```. Could that be the reason? Altough luatex act's differently when called as ```lualatex``` and when called as ```luatex```.

Comment: as long as your log says `This is LuaTeX`, you are using the wrong engine. You need `This is LuaHBTeX`. I can't tell you if your system has it, it was added to some texlive 2019 in fall 2019 for testing, but it is available in all texlive only in texlive 2020.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: Ubuntu 20.04's TeX Live 2019 *claims* to provide `luahbtex` (in the description of the `texlive-luatex` package) but in fact it doesn't. To make matters worse it silently links `lualatex-dev`, which is supposed to run on `luahbtex`, to `luatex`.

One can use the following workaround:

1. Download https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luahbtex.x86_64-linux.tar.xz (or whatever corresponds to your architecture). You can use another mirror, of course.
2. Put the `luahbtex` binary from this package into `/usr/local/bin` and in the same directory create `lualatex-dev` as a soft link to `luahbtex`.
3. In `/var/lib/texmf/fmtutil.cnf-TEXLIVEDIST` change the line

   `lualatex-dev luatex language.dat,language.dat.lua lualatex.ini`

   to

   `lualatex-dev luahbtex language.dat,language.dat.lua lualatex.ini`.

   (That is, change the engine from `luatex` to `luahbtex`.)
4. Run `sudo fmtutil-sys --byfmt=lualatex-dev`.
5. Using `lualatex-dev` you can now compile any TeX file using the `emoji` package or otherwise relying on `luahbtex` without problem. (In case of `emoji` here's no need to use `\setemojifont{}` except you want to change the font the package chooses by itself.)